# Why is position:fixed making div go outside parent

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have made this:
https://jsfiddle.net/f69gu8ss/2/

When I do `position:fixed` the header goes outside the parent. And also when I scroll it goes to the top of the page. I want it to stick below the image. What do I give to `top` to make it stick below the image.. relative to its sibling?

Comment: I have made an edit to the fiddle. Sorry, I pasted the wrong update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your css, add this:

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  width: inherit;
}
```

Also, `jQuery` is used here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var stickyNavTop = $('.header').offset().top;

  var stickyTopNav = function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {
      $('.header').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
      $('.header').removeClass('sticky');
    }
  };

  stickyTopNav();

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    stickyTopNav();
  });
});
```

See this: https://jsfiddle.net/f69gu8ss/5/

Comment: I want the header to be fixed on scrolling

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand properly, what you want? Is it something like you want to make the image disappear and the header sticks to the top when scrolled?

Comment: yes.. when I scroll below the image, I want the header to be fixed

Comment: @boo Well, look at the edited answer if it solves your issue.

Comment: thanks, but how do I avoid making it overflow when `position:fixed` without using `width:90%`

Comment: @boo You may also use `width: inherit;` so that it can inherit the width of it's parent container

Comment: what's this `sticky-top` class. It works even when I comment it out. But when I remove it, it doesn't work.

Comment: @boo But, in this case, it was not necessary at all, look at new update: https://jsfiddle.net/f69gu8ss/5/

Hope you are now fine with this